# Using conditional logic in computed properties fails to update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two fiddles: [A](http://jsfiddle.net/qhdLy234/1/), [B](http://jsfiddle.net/56rmtj2z/1/) (using Vuejs 2.2.4)

I have a computed property which can be changed programmatically (I am using the `get` and `set` methods).

**Expectations**:

1. If the default parameter changes (`this.message`), the computed property (`computedMessage`) must change (default behaviour).
2. If the secondary parameter changes (`this.messageProxy`), only then the computed property must reflect the secondary parameter.

Fiddle A works as expected but Fiddle B doesn't.

**Error**: The default behaviour (point 1) stops after the secondary parameter changes.

The only difference between the fiddles is a `console` statement in the computed property.

---

**Background**: I was trying to set a `computed` property programatically. The `computed` property is set like:

```
computedMessage: {
  get () {
    let messageProxy = this.messageProxy
    this.messageProxy = null
    console.log(messageProxy, this.messageProxy, this.message)
    return messageProxy || this.message
  },
  set (val) {
    this.messageProxy = val
  }
}
```

This allows me to set the value of `computedMessage` like:

```
this.computedMessage = 'some string'
```

If these lines:

```
get () {
  let messageProxy = this.messageProxy
  this.messageProxy = null
  return messageProxy || this.message
}
```

were to be replaced with:

```
get () {
  return this.messageProxy || this.message
}
```

then `computedMessage` can no longer get access to `this.message` the moment `this.messageProxy` is set.

By setting `this.messageProxy` to `null` I ensure that the

```
computedMessage = this.messageProxy
```

only if an assignment is made.

Comment: Where's the console statement?

Comment: You should find this in fiddle A `console.log(messageProxy, this.messageProxy, this.message)`

Comment: Ok. In future, please include all relevant code _in the question itself_. (See [mcve])

Comment: @evolutionxbox I made the edit as per your suggestion.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Borjante I want a computed property that can also be modified, computed properties can't normally be assigned a value. Also, refer to both the fiddles and run them, they're are both almost exactly the same but the behaviour is different.

Comment: Yes, that's why they are computed, you can always reach out to a normal function, looks like you are not needing the auto-computed side of this

Comment: @Borjante This is a simulation of a case. There are quite a lot of instances to require [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference to `this.message` in the return statement isn't triggering `computedMessage` to update. This is because its location in the logical `||` statement makes it inaccessible. It's a gotcha documented in the [Vue.js Computed Properties Documentation](http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/computed.html).

From the Docs:

```
status: function () {
    return this.validated
        ? this.okMsg
        : this.errMsg // errMsg isn't accessible; won't trigger updates to status
}
```

The workaround is to explicitly access dependencies:

```
status: function () {
    // access dependencies explicitly
    this.okMsg
    this.errMsg
    return this.validated
        ? this.okMsg
        : this.errMsg
}
```

So in your example add a reference to `this.message`:

```
get() {
  this.message
  let messageProxy = this.messageProxy
  this.messageProxy = null
  return messageProxy || this.message
}
```

The reason your first fiddle was working as expected was because the `console.log` call had `this.message` as a parameter.

Comment: I too noticed this, the intent of my question is to know the reason :)

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Found the reason in the documentation, see edit

Comment: I really had no idea about that, thanks! also please edit your answer to contain the documented part of the code.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal No problem. But what do you mean "documented part of the code"?

Comment: In the documentation link, there is an example which illustrates that just having `this.<property>` will add it to monitored dependencies. The solution you have posted has local variables involved which as I see wouldn't be required. (just for reference' sake)

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem with your code is that you are changing data values in your `get` function, and they are data values that trigger the re-computation of the `get` function. Don't do that. The `get` should just be computing a value based on other values. In this case, it should be

```
    get () {
      console.log(this.messageProxy, this.message);
      return this.messageProxy || this.message;
    },
```

With or without the `console` message, it will do what it is supposed to do.

Having re-checked your expectations, I see that you want the override to be cleared whenever the default message changes. You can do that with an additional `watch`:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'I am a great guy',
      messageProxy: null,
      someText: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedMessage: {
      get() {
        return this.messageProxy || this.message
      },
      set(val) {
        this.messageProxy = val
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    overrideComputed() {
      this.computedMessage = this.someText
    }
  },
  watch: {
    message: function() {
      this.messageProxy = null;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>This message must reflect value of input1</p>
  <div>
    {{ computedMessage }}
  </div>

  input1: <input type="text" v-model='message'>

  <div>
    <p>This will cause computed message to reflect input2</p>
    input2: <input type="text" v-model='someText'>
    <button @click='overrideComputed'>Override</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: You don't really need a settable computed here. You could have `overrideComputed` set `messageProxy` directly.

Comment: If I do so ill no longer get `this.message` returned from the getter.

Comment: You will if `this.messageProxy` is empty.

Comment: To reset `this.messageProxy` I had that particular way as in the fiddle. If I do it anywhere else, wouldn't the dependency on `this.messageProxy` cause the `computedMessage` to be run again?

Comment: Why would you reset `this.messageProxy` except in `overrideComputed`?

Comment: By reset I meant setting the value to null. If thats what you too meant, then I didnt understand your comment, could you show that with an example?